# Duhamel's formula, variation of constants formula, easy differentiation of the right hand side

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, definite-integrals, euler-mascheroni-constant

Given $\dot{x}(t)=Hx(t)+f(t)$ and $x(0)=x_0$, how can I see that the Lagrange's variation
of constants $$x(t)=e^{Ht}x_0+\int_0^te^{(t-s)H}f(s)ds$$ *is* the right solution to this problem? I'm afraid I cannot differentiate correctly the r.h.s. of this
equation involving the integral$-$I do not know what become that $s$ and $t$ inside the integral after differentiating and how the result will look like.

Comment: It's not correct, but it's close. Can you explain how you arrived at this function?

Comment: I've simply (incorrectly) copied it from books.google.com with search form containing "differentiating the right hand side" "variation of constants".See the unique result there.But still I do not understand the principle of this equation.

Comment: Ah yes, there's the H now.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'd like to see the treatment with this equation. It should be very standard one, but I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like differentiating the second term on the RHS in $t$ you can use another approach.  Assume that $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $I$ is a nondegenerate integral, is continuous.  Let $x(t_0) = x_0$.  Consider 
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{-tH} x(t)) = - H e^{-tH} x(t) + e^{tH} \dot{x}(t), \quad \forall{t \in I},
$$
which is equal to
$$
- H e^{-tH} x(t) + e^{-tH} \dot{x}(t) = - H e^{-tH} x(t) + e^{-tH} (H x(t) + f(t)).
$$
Since $H e^{-t H} = e^{-t H} H$, we obtain
$$
\frac{d}{dt} (e^{-tH} x(t)) = e^{-tH} f(t).
$$
Integrating the above we have
$$
e^{-tH} x(t) - e^{-t_0 H}  x_0 = \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} e^{-s H} f(s) \, ds, \quad \forall{t_0, t \in I},
$$
which gives
$$
x(t) = e^{(t - t_0)} x_0 + \int\limits_{t_0}^{t} e^{(t -s) H} f(s) \, ds, \quad \forall{t_0, t \in I}.
$$

Comment: Sorry if my question is stupid, but I do not see how it proves that $x(t)$ is the solution ? I do not see at what step the fact that $x(t)$ satisfies $x’(t) = Hx(t)+f(t)$ appears ?

Comment: Look at the passage from the first to the second display: this fact is used on the right-hand side.

Comment: Thank you very much ! But why this process shows that $x(t)$ is a solution ? To be sure to understand : your procedure is to start from a condition that should satisfy a solution in order to find it more easily (by taking the derivative which will be simple to integrate after) instead of proving directly that this $x(t)$ works ?

Comment: @coboy: All the passages are equivalences (at least, under the assumption that $f$ is continuous).

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Here is verification that the function satisfies the DE. Uniqueness depends on the function $f$ being "nice enough".

When you differentiate the integral, you have to treat it like a product since the variable you are differentiating w.r.t. ($t$), shows up in both the integrand and limits.

Comment: But the very last $s$ in your draft should be $t$ for the equality with the l.h.s. to hold?

Comment: Yes, it should be a t starting from the third to the last line down. Do you understand why?

Comment: Not clearly enough.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of calculus. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus

Comment: Very nice. You should consider using MathJax (based on LaTeX syntax) so that you don't have to embed images in your answers.

Comment: I do when I'm not working from my phone. I haven't found an efficient way to write in LaTeX on a mobile device.

Comment: @Daniel I'm happy with this answer anyway.

Comment: @Daniel But still, though that $t$ is in the limit of the integral and at the same time in the integrand, why do we use the product rule for the differentiation while we integrate by $s$ and not $t$? Thank you