# How to differentiate $\int_{\tau}^t \Phi(t, s)b(s)ds$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The solution $x(t, \tau, \xi)$ of $\dot{x} = A(t)x + b(t)$ , which passes the point $(\tau, \xi)$,  is $$x(t, \tau, \xi)=\Phi(t, \tau)\xi + \int_{\tau}^t \Phi(t, s)b(s)ds, $$ where $\Phi(t, s) = (x(t, s, e_1), \ldots, x(t, s, e_n))$.

I want to confirm it, but how do I differentiate $\displaystyle\int_{\tau}^t \Phi(t, s)b(s)ds$ ?

Comment: Maybe *Leibniz's integral rule* may help you out, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule (I assume you're interested in the derivative with respect to $t$)

Comment: If you don't like differentiating an integral with respect to a variable occurring both in the integrand and the integration limit, see my answer to [Duhamel's formula, variation of constants formula, easy differentiation of the right hand side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343994/duhamels-formula-variation-of-constants-formula-easy-differentiation-of-the-r).