# Find recurrent formula for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

Here is the problem: 
$$F'(u)=\frac{l}{c}[F(u)-F(u-m)]$$

$$F(u)=\frac{c-lm}{c}e^\frac{lu}{c} $$ for $0\le u \le m$

Prove that for $km\le u \le (k+1)m$

$$F(u)=F(km)e^\frac{l(u-km)}{c}-\frac{l}{c}\int_{0}^{u-km} F(u-y-m)e^\frac{ly}{c}.$$

Comment: That's not a differential equation. It is a differential-difference equation which is a much different beast.

Comment: Have you tried induction on $k$?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work.

Comment: A hint:  **On each $[km,(k+1)m]$** look on the delay differential equation (DDE) as a nonhomogeneous linear ODE, and notice that the formula looked-for is just [Duhamel's formula for ODEs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2343994/duhamels-formula-variation-of-constants-formula-easy-differentiation-of-the-r). Induction is, in fact, not needed here (perhaps in a very rudimentary form).